# Vue.js Display call one component from another component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have 2 components:

```
Vue.component('repo-button', {
  props:["check_in_id", "repo_id"],
  template: '#repo-button',
  methods: {
    fetchRepo: function() {
        url = window.location.href.split("#")[0] + "/check_ins/" + this.check_in_id + "/repositionings/" + this.repo_id + ".json"
        cl(url)
        cl(this)
        var that;
        that = this;

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            success: function(data) {
                cl(data)
                that.showRepo();
            }
        })

    },
    showRepo: function() {
        // what do I put here to display the modal 
    }
  },
  data: function() {
  var that = this;
  return {

  }
}
});

Vue.component('repo-modal', {
    template: "#repo-modal",
    data: function() {
        return {
            status: 'none'
        }
    }
});

var repositionings = new Vue({
    el: "#repo-vue"
});
```

...and my view consists of a button and a modal.  I'd like the button to call fetchRepo on the `repo-button` component and display the modal (change its `status` property from `none` to `block`.

```
<script type="text/x-template" id="repo-button">
    <div class='socialCircle-item success'>
    <i class='fa fa-comment' 
         @click="fetchRepo"
      :data-check_in='check_in_id' 
      :data-repo='repo_id'> 
    </i>
  </div>
</script>

<script type="text/x-template" id="repo-modal">
    <div  v-bind:style="{ display: status }" class="modal" id="vue-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-client_id="<%= @client.id %>">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body"></div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-simple" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>

<div id="repo-vue">
    <div is="repo-modal"></div>
    <div is="repo-button" repo_id="<%= ci.repositioning.id %>" check_in_id="<%= ci.id %>"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Props down, events up](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Composing-Components)

> In Vue.js, the parent-child component relationship can be summarized
> as props down, events up. The parent passes data down to the child via
> props, and the child sends messages to the parent via events.

In particular, if the state of a component needs to be controlled externally (by a parent or sibling), that state should be passed in as a prop from the parent. Events indicate to the parent that the state should be changed.

Your modal's state is controlled by events in itself and in a sibling component. So the state lives in the parent, and is passed to the modal as a prop. Clicking the modal Close button emits a (custom) `hidemodal` event; clicking the sibling component's comment icon emits a `showmodal` event. The parent handles those events by setting its `showRepoModal` data item accordingly.

```js
Vue.component('repo-button', {
  template: '#repo-button',
  methods: {
    showRepo: function() {
      this.$emit('showmodal');
    }
  }
});

Vue.component('repo-modal', {
  template: "#repo-modal",
  props: ["show"],
  computed: {
    status() {
      return this.show ? 'block' : 'none'
    }
  },
  methods: {
    hideRepo() {
      this.$emit('hidemodal');
    }
  }
});

var repositionings = new Vue({
  el: "#repo-vue",
  data: {
    showRepoModal: false
  }
});
```

```css
.socialCircle-item i {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.2.6/vue.min.js"></script>
<template id="repo-button">
    <div class='socialCircle-item success'>
    <i class='fa fa-comment' 
         @click="showRepo"
         >
    </i>
  </div>
</template>

<template id="repo-modal">
    <div  v-bind:style="{ display: status }" class="modal" id="vue-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" >
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body"></div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" @click="hideRepo" class="btn btn-danger btn-simple" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<div id="repo-vue">
  <div is="repo-modal" :show="showRepoModal" @hidemodal="showRepoModal = false"></div>
  <div is="repo-button" @showmodal="showRepoModal = true"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a great explanation, thank you.  I should create another question for this, but if I want to pass data from the `repo-button` to the modal (for the modal content), how would I do that?

Comment: As an argument in the `emit`, like `this.$emit('showmodal', 'some content');` and your event handler would need to be a method (like `@showmodal="doShowModal"`), which would receive the arguments and deal with them.